# SAPI Recognizer silent failure

Tags: windows-8.1, sapi

I created an InProc recognizer with LANGID=0x409 USEnglish (which is the same as the current locale), and it works. However, when I switch to LANGID=0x809 UKEnglish, all SAPI calls succeed, including creating the recognizer and loading the grammar, but no recognition events are generated. 
Initially when I call IspRecognizer->GetStatus the AUDIO state is SPAS_RUN and the ulNumActive > 0. Shortly thereafter, when I call GetStatus it says the AUDIO state is SPAS_CLOSED, and that no rules are active, which makes it seem the recognizer has shut down, however as I mentioned no api calls failed. I'm using an srgs grammar. I've tried setting its xml:lang to "en" and "en-GB" with no effect.

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: When you switched to the new langid, did you specifically request a recognizer that matched that langid?  (For that matter, what language are you using, c# or c++?)

Comment: First let's eliminate a few things. In your SRGS grammar file are the scopes of your rules set to "public"?

Comment: Yes, I successfully obtained the recognizer for 0x809 (its shown in the recognizer status) and I'm using C++. The srgs file works with English US - it has a public rule. I actually found a workaround after posting this question - which was to call IspGrammarBuilder::ResetGrammar with the language, before loading the grammar (it's a static grammar btw). After doing that it works as expected.